# Su aplicacion de ha detenido WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, webview, webview-android

He desarrollado una aplicación que consta de un Main Activity y otras 9 activitys mas, 6 de estas activitys solo contienen un WebView

**El problema:**
Al abrir una de estas activitys de WebView no ocurre nada, pero al abrir por segunda vez alguna con WebView la aplicación de cierra, independiente mente de cual activity sea.

Comment: Me imagino que se llena la memoria Ram o algo por el estilo, gracias de ante mano

Comment: Puedes poner el log del error para poder entender mejor el problema saludos.

Comment: Si desarrollas aplicaciones Android es importante el uso del LogCat, agrega el mensaje que se muestra y el código con explicación de lo que realiza, es importante ya que lo que comentas puede ser ocasionado por infinidad de causas. Revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: Ya lo corregí amigos, igual gracias por su ayuda, solo borre el historial después de cerrar cada actividad